# Missing namespace 'BaseMeshEffect' in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm getting an error CS0246 saying the file 'BaseMeshEffect' could not be found. But the same project in my colleagues computers work fine. Where can I find this file?

Assets/_UI/Packages/Gamestrap UI/Effects/ShadowEffect.cs(11,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BaseMeshEffect' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I just found this thread, I'm one of the creator of Gamestrap UI and I saw you were having an issue with it, Unity upgraded it's version and changed a lot of stuff in the effects section, I've already uploaded a new version of the asset so it can work with the 5.2 version and the older versions as well, you just have to redownload the asset and it should work. Hope you are liking Gamestrap!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a different version of Unity than your colleagues.  Update to Unity 5.2.

[Reference](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/basevertexeffect-change-to-basemesheffect.338455/)